# Animated color changing underline effect

Tags: html, css

I had a go at trying to figure this out, though I could not understand what code he had used.

http://riccardozanutta.com/

I want to recreate something similar to the effect he has on the top right hand corner. Where the animated sliding bar changes color as it appears and vanishes.

I am pretty sure the code from http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/ is the basis for this. I have managed to get the sliding bar to change color using it, but it is not as smooth and the color change is too sudden.

My attempt:
http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/mOmzVp

```
/* CSS */

.sliding-u-l-r-l {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    transition: width 0s ease, background .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: blue;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0s ease;
}
```

.

```
<!-- HTML -->
    <a class=sliding-u-l-r-l href="http://codepen.io">A link that is and never is</a>
```

Comment: is the codepen causing issues?

Comment: Dude, I'm sorry. I didn't even notice it... <foot in mouth>

Comment: Well tbh I should probably start using code snippit, I get the feeling codepen is kinda frowned down on here?

Comment: Actually, I **prefer** a JSFiddle, CodePen, Plunker, etc... They're easier to edit and modify.

Comment: How much longer do you want it?

Comment: Well rather then the color automatically changing from red to blue the moment I move the mouse, I want the previous color to slide off before the second color also slides off.

Comment: So are you looking for something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/pEiHKq5B3WgleKetMVrD?p=preview)? **Note:** If this is what you want, I'll post it as an answer with an explanation of how it works. The letters "A" and "B" are just temporary placeholders... Don't worry about them.

Comment: Pretty much what I was originally looking for, though tbh I like your version better. Is it quite easy to speed the animation up?

Comment: Ah figured out how to adjust the timing. I have one more random issue though. I have combined this with a resizing header and the sliding-url stops working, I have been able to isolate the issue to the line-height in the "header nav" element. Any idea what would cause this? http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/bBRejp

Comment: I wasn't able to identify what the problem was in your CodePen example.

Comment: If you have any issues, please comment on my answer. ;)

Comment: Sorry ^_^; I forgot to post saying I managed to resolve it in the end, @Chiller gave me some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're looking for something like this:**

*HTML*

```
<a class=sliding-u-l-r-l href="http://codepen.io">A link that is and never is</a>
```

*CSS*

```
.sliding-u-l-r-l {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:before {
    /*
      We moved the background color in here so that we remain
      visible after the link has been unhovered.
    */
    background: red;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    /*
      Take 1 second for the red underline's change in width to take affect.
      We don't want the background to fade out, so we removed the
      background transition.
      */
    transition: width 1s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: blue;
    /*
      Change 1s to whatever length of time you want the blue underline to take.
      */
    transition: width 1s ease;
    /*
      Don't do our transition until the red underline has finished theirs.
      This should be at least as long as the length of the red transition.
    */
    transition-delay: 1s;
    /*
      Make sure the blue underline shows underneath the red one.
    */
    z-index: -1;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:hover:before {
    /*
      We don't need a background color in here anymore.
    */
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
.sliding-u-l-r-l:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0s ease;
}
```

---

**Other:**

*PS:* If you have any questions or need any additional clarification, just ask.

*PPS:* [Here's a link to an example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pEiHKq5B3WgleKetMVrD?p=preview)

*P^3S:* The CSS is commented. If something doesn't make sense or you don't understand something, you might find the explanation in the CSS comments.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help!